# How to Expand/Collapse Collection view section in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How to expand/collapse Collection view section by taping on the header of collection view in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to show section only, and expand/collapse cells.

Then You can treat your section as a particular cell, once you want to expand/collapse, add/remove data and then call "reloadRowsAtIndexpaths" method.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I guess there is some 3rd party work done on this over [here](https://github.com/touchlane/CampcotCollectionView)

The basic idea is to roll out your own `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass and proceed from there on. But as you can see in the repo, the devil is *in the details*.